# Shell script: how to read an optional argument. If the argument does not exist, then use a default value

Tags: shell

I want to write a shell script that can have an optional argument and if there is no optional argument, then uses a default value.
Example: `if sys.argv[1].exists() ip = sys.argv[1] else ip = '10.9.2.16'`

Comment: what shell script variant are you using? `sys.argv[]...` looks like java or js or ?? Powershell? If so, use the correct tag. For typical *nix shells, there are several (which are hard to research), `${var:-tmpDefValue} , ${var:=AssignThisValueIfVarIsEmpty} ${var:?ErrMsg}` .. hm one more, but late, got to go. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you've selected the correct tag and are submitting a question about Unix/Linux command line interpreters, and that the example code you wrote was a pseudocode example to explain the desired behavior.

From the [manpage for bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), in the "Parameter Expansion" section, it clearly indicates how to do this with any variable, not just positional parameters:

> ${parameter:-word}
>
> ```
>    Use Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null, 
>    the expansion of word is substituted.
>    Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.
> ```

This will work for POSIX shell as well, and all dialects of shell script that I know of.
So for your example, you could use:

```
#!/bin/sh
ip=${1:-10.9.2.16}
echo "IP is $ip"
```

`/path/to/script.sh` would output: `IP is 10.9.2.16`.
`/path/to/script.sh 8.8.8.8` would output: `IP is 8.8.8.8`.

If you mean that you want `$1` to be optional, but that you want other arguments after it, you could explicitly omit the first argument and allow it to fallback to the default by calling the script with a pair of quotes (single or double) in place of the first argument.
For example, with the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
ip=${1:-10.9.2.16}
echo "IP is $ip"
echo "Your second argument is $2"
```

Calling it like `/path/to/script.sh "" quux` would output:

```
IP is 10.9.2.16
Your second argument is quux
```

Answer (score 0):

As Wilson commented, In shell scripting you can use the ${parameter:-default} syntax to read an optional argument and use a default value if the argument does not exist. Here is an example:

```
optional_arg=${1:-default_value}
echo "The value of the optional argument is: $optional_arg"
```

This sets the variable optional_arg to the value of the first argument passed to the script ($1), or the default value "default_value" if the first argument is not provided.

You can also use if statement with [ -z "$variable" ] to check if variable is empty or not.

```
if [ -z "$optional_arg" ]; then
   optional_arg="default_value"
fi
```